# WebSQL transaction error not enough storage space?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-sql

I tried create websql database. `openDatabase` renurn value not null, but `database.transaction` return not enough remaining storage space error.

I have this code

```
const database = openDatabase("testDB","1.0","my test db",1024*1024*2);

database.transaction(
    function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,todo_item TEXT,due_date VARCHAR)", [], function(execErr) {
            console.log(execErr);
        });
    },

    function(txErr) {
        console.log(txErr);
    }
);
```

Chrome 69.0.3497.100
Return in `console.log(txErr);` this error
[image]

> there was not enough remaining storage space, or the storage quota was reached and the user declined to allow more space

What could be the reason?

Comment: (Please include error messages as quotes (block-quotes if multi-line), not as pictures so they can be found by searches even in 2018.)

Comment: edited questions text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change db name to random word, db verison to 0.1 and this work for me.